# UserControl Dimensions Ignored in MainPage Layout

Tags: wpf, silverlight-4.0, wpf-controls, grid

I have a `Canvas` with a `Grid` on it. The Grid contains 3 columns. The first column contains another `Grid`, the second contains nothing, the third contains an Image (a box). (I have the blank column for animation purposes unrelated to this question.)

In my child `Grid` I have 2 rows. The first row contains a UserControl (shelves of boxes), the second contains an Image (a barcode).

The problem is that the layout engine seems to completely ignore the dimensions of the user control. In the preview I see my UserControl and directly on top of it the two other images. Granted `Canvas` doesn't automatically size its children, but I have that resolved with some resize statements in the `SizeChanged` event of the page.

As it is, the box shows up at runtime in the bottom right corner of my window as it should, however the barcode appears positioned as if the UserControl doesn't exist.

For an illustration of my issue please see http://www.wynright.com/temp/Problem.png

The following is my XAML code:

```
<Canvas x:Name="MainCanvas" Background="Silver">
    <Grid Name="LayoutRoot">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid Name="LayoutChild" Grid.Column="0">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <LightPickDemo:Picker x:Name="PickZone" ZoneCleared="PickZone_ZoneCleared" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
            <Image Name="BarCode" Source="/LightPickDemo;component/Images/BarcodeScan.png" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Stretch="None" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="1" />
        </Grid>
        <Image Name="imgShippingBox" Source="/LightPickDemo;component/Images/Empty-Box.png" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Stretch="None" Grid.Column="2" />
    </Grid>
</Canvas>
```

So I wonder what do I need to do to get the UserControl to offer its size for the layout engine. I can see in my designer the size of the control, so clearly the compiler knows that there is size to this control.

I would like the barcode to show centered below the UserControl.

Here is the XAML for the UserControl:

```
<Canvas>
    <Image Name="ImageBase" Source="/LightPickDemo;component/Images/BayShelves.png" />
    <LightPickDemo:ZoneLight x:Name="ZoneLight" Canvas.Left="345" Canvas.Top="0" ButtonPress="ZoneLight_ButtonPress" />
    <LightPickDemo:PickerModule x:Name="pickerCalculator" Canvas.Left="74" Canvas.Top="266" OnPicked="Picker_PickChanged" />
    <LightPickDemo:PickerModule x:Name="pickerCalendar" Canvas.Left="207" Canvas.Top="266" OnPicked="Picker_PickChanged" />
    <LightPickDemo:PickerModule x:Name="pickerPaperClip" Canvas.Left="521" Canvas.Top="266" OnPicked="Picker_PickChanged" />
    <LightPickDemo:PickerModule x:Name="pickerRuler" Canvas.Left="649" Canvas.Top="266" OnPicked="Picker_PickChanged" />
    <LightPickDemo:PickerModule x:Name="pickerScissor" Canvas.Left="75" Canvas.Top="532" OnPicked="Picker_PickChanged" />
    <LightPickDemo:PickerModule x:Name="pickerStapler" Canvas.Left="250" Canvas.Top="532" OnPicked="Picker_PickChanged" />
    <LightPickDemo:PickerModule x:Name="pickerStapleRemover" Canvas.Left="435" Canvas.Top="532" OnPicked="Picker_PickChanged" />
    <LightPickDemo:PickerModule x:Name="pickerTapeDispenser" Canvas.Left="635" Canvas.Top="532" OnPicked="Picker_PickChanged" />
</Canvas>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An answer to my question seems to be to put the following code in my UserControl, however, I can't imagine this is the best answer and I know it doesn't allow for screen scaling at all. So please, if anyone knows how to do this correctly, please let me know.

Thanks to [Wallstreet Programmer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5558441/usercontrol-dimensions-ignored-in-mainpage-layout/5567008#5567008) for leading me to this workaround.

```
Protected Overrides Function MeasureOverride(ByVal availableSize As System.Windows.Size) As System.Windows.Size
    Dim bmp As BitmapImage
    bmp = BaseImage.Source
    Return New Size(bmp.PixelWidth, bmp.PixelHeight)
    'Return MyBase.MeasureOverride(availableSize)
End Function
```

Comment: It occurred to me that `Canvas` doesn't allow screen scaling anyway; therefor, this is the best answer that I can find for now. If anyone has a better solution I'll be glad to entertain it and give them credit if it works.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the `ActualHeight` of your user control is zero. Looking at your XAML for the user control you should be able to just set `Height` and `Width` in the XAML of the user control.

Comment: But I don't want to. I want the UserControl to be sized dynamically and as its size changes, the parent to react accordingly. Right now the only size changes I'll have is a different picture of shelves on load, but in the future there my be periodic update of the image during runtime. How do I get the layout to work with these conditions?

Comment: I just checked: the ActualHeight is indeed 0. Why would it be 0, even after everything is loaded and rendered? After all, I see the image and it _clearly_ isn't 0.

Answer (score 0):

I can't determine what is the UserControl from your image, but if you set the property to 'collapsed' the engine won't read the size I don't think. If the UserControl isn't visible, but you want to show the dimensions, animate the opacity property instead of visibility. The barcode is in Row 1 which is the top row, should it be in row 2?

Am I correct in assuming the barcode needs to be below the image with the 2 rows of boxes? Where is the UserControl? What is it?

Comment: I thought that row 0 was the top row and row 1 was the second row. In any case, changing row 1 to row 2 doesn't make a difference.